# How can I specify dimension order when using ncdf4::ncvar_get?

Tags: r, netcdf

Following a previous question ([Faster reading of time series from netCDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19936432/199217)) I have re-permuted my netCDF files to provide fast time-series reads ([scripts on github to be cleaned up eventually ...](https://github.com/ebimodeling/model-drivers/tree/master/met/cruncep)).

In short, to make reads faster, I have rearranged the dimensions from `lat, lon, time` to `time, lat, lon`. Now, my existing scripts break because they assume that the dimensions will always be `lat, lon, time`, following the ncdf4 documentation of `ncvar_get`, for the 'start' argument:

> Order is X-Y-Z-T (i.e., the time dimension is last)

However, this is not the case.

Furthermore, there is a related inconsistency in the order of variables listed via the commandline netCDF utility `ncdump -h` and the R function `ncdf4::nc_open`. The first says that the dimensions are in the expected (lat, lon, time) order while the latter sees dimensions with time first (time, lat, lon).

For a minimal example, download the file [test.nc](https://www.box.com/s/kuz1whrixxnwgouamtoe) and run

```
bash-$ ncdump -h .nc
bash-$ R
R> library(ncdf4)
R> print(nc_open("test.nc")
```

What I want to do is get records 5-15 from the variable "lwdown"

```
my.nc <- nc_open("test.nc")
```

But this doesn't work, since R sees the time dimension first, so I must change my scripts to

```
ncvar_get(my.nc, "lwdown", start = c(5, 1, 1), count = c(10, 1, 1))
```

It wouldn't be so bad to update my scripts and functions, except that I want to be able to read data from files regardless of the dimension order.

Other than Is there a way to generalize this function so that it works independent of dimension order?

Answer (score 3):

While asking the question, I figured out this solution, though there is still room for improvement:

The closest I can get is to open the file and find the order in this way:

```
my.nc$var$lwdown$dim[[1]]$name
[1] "time"
my.nc$var$lwdown$dim[[2]]$name
[1] "lon"
my.nc$var$lwdown$dim[[3]]$name
[1] "lat"
```

which is a bit unsatisfying, although it led me to this solution:

If I want to start at `c(lat = 1, lon = 1, time = 5)`, but the `ncvar_get` expects an arbitrary order, I can say"

```
start <- c(lat = 1, lon = 1, time = 5)
count <- c(lat = 1, lon = 1, time = 10)
dim.order <- sapply(my.nc$var$lwdown$dim, function(x) x$name)

ncvar_get(my.nc, "lwdown", start = start[dim.order], count = count[dim.order])
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this recently as well.  I have a netcdf with data in this format

```
nc_in <- nc_open("my.nc")

nc_in$dim[[1]]$name == "time"
nc_in$dim[[2]]$name == "latitude"
nc_in$dim[[3]]$name == "longitude"

nc_in$dim[[1]]$len == 3653 # this is the number of timesteps in my netcdf
nc_in$dim[[2]]$len == 180 # this is the number of longitude cells
nc_in$dim[[3]]$len == 360 # this is the number of latitude cells
```

The obnoxious part here is that the DIM component of the netCDF is in the order of T,Y,X

If I try to to grab time series data for the **pr** var using the indices in the order they appear in **nc_in$dim** I get an error

```
ncvar_get(nc_in,"pr")[3653,180,360] # 'subscript out of bounds'
```

If I instead grab data in X,Y,T order, it works:

```
ncvar_get(nc_in,"pr")[360,180,3653] # gives me a value
```

What I don't understand is how the ncvar_get() package knows what variable represents X, Y and T, especially if you have generated your own netCDF.